# Node.JS: Cannot find module './abort.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using node.js v17.3.0 and im trying to upload my Discord bot to my raspberry pi. On my local PC it works, but on my raspi i get this error:
Anyone has a solution for that?

````
[Bot-Handler] Starting Bot...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module './abort.js'
Require stack:
- /home/excerz/node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js
- /home/excerz/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js
- /home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js
- /home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js
- /home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/excerz/main.js
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/excerz/node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js:1:13)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [
   '/home/excerz/node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js',
   '/home/excerz/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js',
   '/home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js',
   '/home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js',
   '/home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js',
   '/home/excerz/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js',
   '/home/excerz/main.js'
 ]
}

Node.js v17.3.0```
````

Comment: You've provided an incorrect path or the file doesn't exist

Comment: No, its a node internal error. I dont have a file called abort.js